# How would play sound and not get an Exception?

Tags: java, audio

I've got this class for playing sound but every time I try to use it I get a null pointer exception. This is how I'm using it:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Sound {

public Clip play(String filename) {
    Clip clip = null;

    try {
        AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource(filename));
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioIn);
        clip.start();
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return clip;
    }

}

public Sound sound; 
sound.play("PathToFile");
```

Comment: It would help people answer your question if you add the stack trace of the exception you're getting (particularly which line of the code is throwing the `NullPointerException`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
File file = new File(filename);
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(file.getPath());
```

Comment: Tried but still getting this:java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileReader.getSequence(Unknown Source)
 at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequence(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at net.delta.pixeluniverse.Sound.play(Sound.java:11)
 at net.delta.pixeluniverse.Menu.<init>(Menu.java:56)
 at net.delta.pixeluniverse.Component.main(Component.java:213)

Comment: Try adding "getPath()" and double check your file value doesn't have any typo.

Comment: It says: "The method getPath() is undefined for the type String"

Comment: I see what is going on here, you need to initialize a file object before calling getResource: Put `File file= new File(filename)` right after your try. And call getResource on file instead of filename.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize the sound variable? You should do something like:

```
Sound sound = new Sound(); //Notice the 'new' keyword here
sound.play("PathToFile");
```